# attributed strings with emojis - proper height

Tags: ios, nsstring, uilabel, nsattributedstring, emoji

I'm trying to get the height of an attributed string. This is working as expected with:

```
[attrString boundingRectWithSize:size
                         options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingTruncatesLastVisibleLine)
                         context:NULL]
```

...unless the string contains emojis. With emojis, the string is cut off at the bottom of the label sized with this. Is there something special I need to do?

Comment: Were you able to fix this? I have the exact same issue.

Comment: if you take off the option NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading, it may work fine but I wonder what exactly NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading does to calculate height

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post but someone might still find it useful, you could drop to core text and let that do the hard work for you!

```
static inline CGSize OKASizeWithAttributedString(NSAttributedString *attributedString, CGFloat width) {

  CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((__bridge CFAttributedStringRef)attributedString);
  CGSize targetSize = CGSizeMake(width, CGFLOAT_MAX);
  CGSize size = CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints(framesetter, CFRangeMake(0, (CFIndex)[attributedString length]), NULL, targetSize, NULL);
  CFRelease(framesetter);

  return size;
}
```

Comment: @Oliver Atkinson: I have used ur code.it working fine,but if there is lot of space in text then it won't worked properly.

Comment: @bittu what font are you using? With fonts supported by the system it is ok, I have generally seen problems when using custom fonts

Comment: I tried this code with both system and custom (Avenir next)font.issue arrive in both.One more thing..it worked on small text for both font but if text is too large then it not worked.

Comment: I have tried same in swift but CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints() method is returning zero size so, @OliverAtkinson can plz tell it's swift version.

Answer (score 0):

```
+(CGFloat)heightStringWithEmojis:(NSString*)str fontType:(UIFont *)uiFont ForWidth:(CGFloat)width {

    // Get text
    CFMutableAttributedStringRef attrString = CFAttributedStringCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);
    CFAttributedStringReplaceString (attrString, CFRangeMake(0, 0), (CFStringRef) str );
    CFIndex stringLength = CFStringGetLength((CFStringRef) attrString);

    // Change font
    CTFontRef ctFont = CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef) uiFont.fontName, uiFont.pointSize, NULL);
    CFAttributedStringSetAttribute(attrString, CFRangeMake(0, stringLength), kCTFontAttributeName, ctFont);

    // Calc the size
    CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(attrString);
    CFRange fitRange;
    CGSize frameSize = CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints(framesetter, CFRangeMake(0, 0), NULL, CGSizeMake(width, CGFLOAT_MAX), &fitRange);

    CFRelease(ctFont);
    CFRelease(framesetter);
    CFRelease(attrString);

    return frameSize.height;

}
```